# Hello Guys i,m trying to generate the GitHub pages but i,m failed

Tags: github-pages

I'm trying to generate the GitHub pages but don't get the point actually I want upload the my site. So guys guide me step by step please I'm waiting your answers.

Comment: Tell us what you've tried so far, then we'll help you. What tutorial are you using? Also, Is this a programming question? Maybe try superuser?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site

You should read about it first.
like :

1. create repository and commit push your code into that repo.
2. Go to repo's setting and select source folder under the pages section where your entry point of site(index.html) is placed.
3. and that's it. after 1-2 minute, your site is live.

Note : Your repo must be public. otherwise github pages won't work.
github pages feature does not providing server in free. So we can't run DB operation and server code over there.

Comment: fyi the question itself is off-topic (it's not a programming question, and it's asking for documentation). If you're going to share that doc link, it should be a comment, not in an answer.